# Visual Studio changes debug xml Command line arguments

Tags: xml, visual-studio, command-line-arguments

In Visual Studio -> Debug -> Command line arguments 
enter the following XML.

```
"<AppParameters><ConnectionString>Server=localhost;Database=MyDB;User Id=sa;Password=YouNameIt</ConnectionString></AppParameters>"
```

Then you read this with the following lines

```
DataSet parameter = new DataSet();
parameter.ReadXml(new StringReader(xmlParameter));
```

All works great!

Then you restart Visual Studio and after starting your project, you will get this error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

The first time, of course, you will spend some time to investigate what happend. First suggestion of course, your fault. But then you'll see this:

```
"<AppParameters xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"><ConnectionString>Server=localhost;Database=MyDB;User Id=sa;Password=YouNameIt</ConnectionString></AppParameters>"
```

Visual Studio has changed the command line arguments.

Why?!

Comment: Any reason for not using the App.config/Web.config file for the project to store connection strings?

Comment: Are you **sure** you can use such special characters in command line? Even if quoted?

Comment: That's not the type of thing you pass at the command line typically, so if you have problems doing so I'm not surprised. As far as why it was changed: it's probably because VS wrote the XML to save it, and the XML persistence code is written to add the MSBuild namespace to the XML.

Comment: @Jontatas: Because it must be passed to the application dynamically before runtime.

Comment: @Adriano Repetti: Yes, I have tested it in production, and it's working perfect.

Comment: @Ken White: Please think about first, what I am trying here, before answering anything else. I do not have problems with that, so there are no surprises at runtime at all. The only surprise is, that Visual Studio can not handle it for some reasons, but DataSet can. And do not mention just something! When using DataSet.WriteXml it does not change the xml at all, so why does Visual Studio?

Comment: @user3797717 first of all we're all here trying to help so please **be kind**. For second I repeat my question: are you sure you can use such special characters in command line (within Visual Studio)? Answer is **no** because it'll do two things: kindly escape `<` and `>` with command line rules with `^` (and you can't omit quotes because of spaces in your text). Second and most important using quotes you bypass XML escaping it uses (try by yourself).

Comment: You _may_ manually edit .csproj.user to enclose it in a `<![CDATA[` section (it'll work until next change in properties) or do not pass XML as command line argument (as @KenWhite suggested). Usually XML is _"...not the type of thing you pass at command line typically"_ then if you have problems do not do it. Is it something generated by a program? Use a response file (or redirect stdin). Is it something entered by user? Use true command line options. If VS has this bug it means they didn't find it in 12 years, there should be a reason for this...

Answer (score 0):

I'm debugging a *Python* module and had the same problem. For more than half hour I went crazy, but finally I've got it. Notes:

- I am using *VS2k10*.
- The *Debugging* related settings are stored in the *vcxproj.user* file (I am going to refer to it as *VUF*).

While having the solution open, I started by removing *VUF*. Opening the *Project Property Pages* dialog, the default values are there:

- *Command*: `$(TargetPath)`
- *CommandArguments*:

In the same time *VUF* was generated (I didn't even have to close the dialog). Here's it's content (notice the namespace):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
</Project>
```

Then I populated the above fields (don't mind the values):

- *Command*: `E:\WinOBT\1.0.0.0\OPSWpython\2.7.10\x64_d\python_d.exe`
- *CommandArguments*: `-c "import _xmlrpc as _x;print _x.decode('<value><string>aaa</string></value>')"`

After closing the dialog (or pressing *Apply*), *VUF* content became:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
        <LocalDebuggerCommand>E:\WinOBT\1.0.0.0\OPSWpython\2.7.10\x64_d\python_d.exe</LocalDebuggerCommand>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
        <LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>-c "import _xmlrpc as _x;print _x.decode('<value><string>aaa</string></value>')"</LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>
        <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

while *CommandArguments* became: `-c "import _xmlrpc as _x;print _x.decode('<value xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"><string>aaa</string></value>')"`

*VS* as we know, stores its settings in *xml* format (not the string representation in the file, but the actual *xml* tree - that results from parsing the string representation). Well, I've learned that parsing an *xml* string (that converts it to a tree), then converting back the tree to string, will yield (in most of the cases) a different result than the original string.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33288996/python-manipulate-and-save-xml-change-one-property) I described this behavior (well it's about a *Python* parser, but I'm sure that all - or many - behave the same).

So, we have an *xml* (that we would like to be stored as plain text) inside an *xml* (the project settings), and that confuses a little *VS*'s parser when it attempts to parse it, yielding a behavior that I think it's odd:

- if it succeeds:

  - it will add the `xmlns` attribute, and therefore messing up the original *xml* text in the dialog box, and also when passing to the program
  - it will store it as we passed it in *VUF*
- if it fails for some reason (e.g. *xml* is invalid):

  - it will store as we passed it in the dialog box (and it will properly pass it as an argument to the executable being debugged)
  - it will escape the *xml* special chars in *VUF*

After I circled around i found a way to partially overcome this (it's a lame workaround - or gainarie):

- manually modify *VUF*, turning our *xml* into a [CDATA section](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_cdatasection.asp):

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
          <LocalDebuggerCommand>E:\WinOBT\1.0.0.0\OPSWpython\2.7.10\x64_d\python_d.exe</LocalDebuggerCommand>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
          <LocalDebuggerCommandArguments><![CDATA[-c "import _xmlrpc as _x;print _x.decode('<value><string>aaa</string></value>')"]]></LocalDebuggerCommandArguments>
      <DebuggerFlavor>WindowsLocalDebugger</DebuggerFlavor>
          <LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>$(OutDir)</LocalDebuggerWorkingDirectory>
      </PropertyGroup>
  </Project>
  ```
- Reload the solution (as *VS* doesn't read *VUF* every time we open the dialog since its internal tree hasn't changed)

Now the *xml* string is properly passed to the executable, and also properly displayed in the *Project Property Pages* dialog. **Beware**: if you modify any of the settings, in the dialog, that will trigger VS to reload (reparse) the data, and it will mess it up again.